# How to change content in Wordpress custom page template?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have created a Wordpress page template hoping to display a custom menu and corresponding pages.  My question is really how do I change the content displayed in the template?  I want to replace the menu with whatever page option is selected from the menu.  Php include just adds content to what's already there and the header(location:) function takes me to another php file but then I lose the page template. This is probably so simple, but I'm totally confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might be better asking this question at [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that site.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create your pages inside the WordPress admin. If they don't exist in the admin, you will not (at least, not with some progamming skills) be able to target them and display them with a WordPress template.
Did you do this? Your pages will have urls like http:://yoursite.com/pagename/, etc. 
Then, if you select an option in the menu, you can link the user to the corresponding URL.

Comment: Yes, I created two pages within admin and each uses a unique page template.  They both display fine separately, but when I call one from the other by url the second page displays errors saying that my functions are undefined get_header(), etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "call one from the other"? You call page 2 inside page 1? With an iframe, with fopen()? I do not understand what you are doing. Do you use an include? (PHP). Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I call page 2 from inside page 1 using the form action command.  After the user completes the form the will hit the submit button and it should go to page 2.  I am putting the complete url in quotes after action=  I have spent days trying to figure it out on my own so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK then, I think you want to create what is called a "jump menu": when the page name is selected in the dropdown menu, you want the user to be automatically sent to the corresponding page. 
So you might check this little example: http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/jump_menus.asp
Just create all your destination pages in advance in WordPress, note their URL (http://yoursite.com/page1/, http://yoursite.com/page2/, etc.). Put the URL in the value of the option select, and everything should work. You don't want to put the URL of the target page in "action", because that is the URL the form would be sent to and the fact is that you are not using the form as a real form, but as a mean to select an option and get a JavaScript command to execute. See if the tutorial makes it clearer for you, otherwise, keep posting.

Comment: I appreciate, but I'm not using DreamWeaver.  I think the real issue is that when it arrives on page 2 using the link from page 1, none of the functions on page 2 can be found.  Everything is found when I open page 2 separately on its own, but errors out when I open from a link.

Comment: Thank you barakadam, I found out that I needed to point to the url of WordPress page instead of the url of the php file.  This is why none of my functions were being found.  Thank you again for your help.